# Primefaces panels appear open when collapsed is set to true

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, panel

By default when page is loaded the panel appear close because i have the attribute **collapsed="true"**. I want that when i edit an add automatically the panel updates, the update works fine but all the panels appear open even though i have collapsed set to true. I dont know why this happens. Does any knows why? and how to solve this?

addView.xhtml:

```
<body>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./../../resources/css/cssLayout.css"/>
    <ui:composition template="./../../Layouts/LayoutGeneral.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h1 style="text-align: center">Adds</h1> <br/>

            <h:form id="allAddsId">
                <ui:repeat value="#{addBean.allAdds}" var="add" >
                    <p:panel id="basic" header="#{add.title}" style="margin-bottom:20px" toggleable="true" collapsed="true" styleClass="">
                        <p:ajax event="toggle"/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{add.description}" />
                        </h:panelGrid> <br/>

                        <p:separator/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Edit"  oncomplete="PF('detail').show();" update="detailAdd" action="#{addBean.setAddAux(add)}"/>

                        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />
                    </p:panel>
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:form>  

            <p:dialog id="detail" header="Edit Add" widgetVar="detail">
                <p:outputPanel id="detailAdd">
                    <h:form>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Title"/><br/>
                        <p:inputTextarea id="titleEdit" value="#{addBean.addAux.title}" rows="2" cols="50" counter="displayTE" maxlength="50" counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes" autoResize="false" required="true" requiredMessage="Title necesaria"/> <br/>
                        <p:outputLabel id="displayTE"/> <br/> <br/>

                        <p:outputLabel value="Description"/> <br/>
                        <p:inputTextarea id="opcion1" value="#{addBean.addAux.description}" rows="6" cols="50" counter="displayDE" maxlength="200" counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes" autoResize="false" required="true" requiredMessage="Description necesaria"/> <br/>
                        <p:outputLabel id="displayDE"/> <br/> <br/>

                        <p:separator/> <br/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{addBean.editAdd(addBean.addAux)}" onclick="detail.hide()" update=":allAddsId"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>  
                    </h:form>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i found a solution!! i dont know if this is the best answers but here i go..

I was doing somo test and i delete **p:ajax event="toggle"** which is under the panel declaration and now works!! When i edit an add the list of adds automatically updates and the panels appear collapsed!! I dont why deleting that makes it works so if someone knows feel free to tell me!

Hope this help someone!

Comment: Please state your PF version, also in the question